# replacing on mouse selected area in emacs

Tags: replace, emacs, mouse

This is something easily done in nedit, or komodo, but could not find how to do it in emacs.
I highlight an area of my code, using the mouse. Then I just want to do replace or regexp replace, on the area highlighted only.
Any ideas?
A reference to elisp code which enables this is more than welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `query-replace` (by default it is bound to `M-%`), or `M-x query-replace`. If a region is highlighted, it will only do replacements within that region.

If you want to use a regexp, do `M-x replace-regexp` with a region highlighted, and you will have the same behavior.

However, keep in mind that when you are in windowless Emacs in the terminal, this will not work with mouse selection. You can still mark/highlight a region with keyboard commands, and then replacements will only be applied to that region, but if you highlight a region with the mouse, although it will visually be highlighted, Emacs *will not* treat it as a marked/highlighted region. As far as I know, there is no way around this fact in windowless Emacs.

Comment: Works like a charm.
Thanks!

Comment: @user1134991 I am not sure what you mean. Are you triggering `query-replace` with `C-SPC`? If so, I can tell you how to bind it to a different key, but I am not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: That is, selecting the text, by dragging the mouse and using query-replace.<br>
This is rather than pointing, pressing CTL-SPC, pointing at the end (the text is not highlighted in the GUI), and then using the query-replace.
More nedit/komodo like use model. Not a major issue...

Comment: @user1134991 sorry, I am still not following you. You *can* select text by dragging the mouse and then use `query-replace`, as long as you are in a windowed instance of Emacs.

Comment: Yeah, but then the query-replace is not limited to the highlighted area. I am using a very dated version, though...

Comment: Oh, I see. It is possible your version does not support that. What is your Emacs version (you can get this info by doing `M-x emacs-version`)? I am using `24.5.1`, and in my version `query-replace` will run only on the highlighted region. Again though, if you are using Emacs on a server that you are sshed into or something like that where you are in terminal Emacs, this will not work in any version of Emacs, AFAIK.

Comment: Daaaamn! You best bet might be to upgrade your Emacs if that is a possibility. I wouldn't be able to test a solution for anything but the version I am using. Sorry!

Comment: I wouldn't either... My I.T., in those things is, shall I say, restrictive? They are not Mordac, preventer of information services, but, less accommodating  than what I would like...